# Take a snapshot of the contents of a Windows console

Tags: python, windows-console

I have a program that produces colored output on the console, and I want to write a test ensuring the output is correct.

On Unix-like systems this is done using [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors), so capturing the output stream is enough to check the rendered colors.

On Windows, I'm using [colorama](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama) to translate the ANSI codes to Win32 API calls. However, I'd still like to ensure the right colors are being produced.

How do I programmatically capture the contents of a Windows console to compare it to the expected output?

Any format is OK as long as the content doesn't spuriously change - HTML, an image, PDF, etc.

The test in question needs to run on AppVeyor, so it probably does not have a graphical environment ready.

Comment: how could you have terminal colors on windows without a graphical terminal? I don't think it works this way.

Comment: On Linux, a virtual PTY can be used to emulate one. Perhaps a console process can be started as a subprocess and communicated with?

Comment: Modern Windows Systems support ANSI colors in the terminal. So I do not get your problem completly. Could you please elaborat a bit more.

Comment: https://github.com/FeodorFitsner/selenium-tests/blob/ce5f4e40efd4b099a8af16c2abe74f8bf108a224/take-screenshot.ps1#L1 + pythonnet

Comment: @xaav I'll accept this if you turn it into an answer!